# Viewing a txt file with row separator "\x00"

Tags: excel, csv, notepad++, libreoffice, separator

I got a program that outputs a txt with column separator "\t" and row separator "\x00" (hex code)

But when I open the txt with MS Excel, Notepad++, LibreOffice, all the contents are put in one row.

But I want to open this in either MS Excel or LibreOffice in the "normal" view so that I can edit it easily.

I tried to find some type of buttons in LibreOffice to change the separator but I couldn't.

I changed encoding of it using Notepad++ to all encodings, but changing encoding didn't help at least at notepad++.

How can I open this file with row separator actually being displayed as it should?

I want to see this in multiple rows and edit it efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++, you can perform a Find and Replace (ctrl+h).

1. Set the Search Mode to Extended
2. For the Find what, enter \\x00
3. For the Replace with, enter \n
4. Hit Replace All

[image: Replace \x00 with new lines]

Then to replace the \t with tabs, you can:

1. For the Find what, enter \\t
2. For the Replace with, enter \t
3. Hit Replace All

[image: Replace \t with tabs]

Comment: This didn't work because notepad++ can't even display \\x00 . \\x00 is displayed as being broken.

Comment: I'd have to see a sample of your data then